# How to upload a file in Webform using javascript to have it access in global PHP variable $_FILES

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file, upload

I need help and almost crazy. I found a shitload of answers but they all do to work or at least work just a bit !?!

My task is to use a html form and upload one file or more to the webserver using ajax und recieving an answer after evaluation of php. Best I want to send form input information as well as file by an $ajax Request.

I do not understand the syntax.
So can the one or other person ...

a) Tell me how to do correctly one and also a list of files.
How to upload form data and files in one go.

b) What is the structure in detail of the file object

file = $('#file0')[0].files[0]   <- I am totally lost, except that
|_____________|              '#file0' is the id of the input
?        |________|     item 'file'
?

in the following piece of code below
Many thanks in advance.
Marvin

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                function ajax_file_upload(){
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    
                    var file;
                    //  file = $('#file0')[0].files[0]
                    //  fd.append('file0', file);
                    
                    var formfiles = document.querySelectorAll('[type=file]');
                    // we start from since the first two input comes from a different form
                    for (let i = 0; i < formfiles.length; i++) {
                    var file = formfiles[i].files[0];
                    var id = 'file' . i;
                    fd.append( id , file );       
                    alert( file.name  );
                    }     

                    $.ajax({
                        url: './ajaxupload.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: fd,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(response){
                            alert(response);                                
                        }, 
                        error: function(response){
                            alert("Error occurred while trying to upload file");
                        }
                    });
                        
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="JavaScript:ajax_file_upload();" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
                <input type="file" id="file0" name="file0" />
                <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" />
                <input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

PHP in script ajaxupload.php:
print_r $_FILES;

Answer (score 0):

I have found the right piece of code I was looking for ...
$.ajax({
...
data: new FormData($('#webform')[0]),
contentType:false,
cache:false,
processData:false,
mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
success: function( upload ){},
...
});